# How to use an IF statement with multiple cells and conditions?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need some assistance with an IF statement/formula.

If G24 is greater than zero, subtract G3 from G24 and display the results in G3 If G24 is null/blank, then keep G3's current value

Here is what I have so far but I know this needs to change.

=IF(G24>0,G3-G24,G3)

Example: Someone works a 40 hour work week so 40 hours is entered in G3.
If a PTO number is entered in G24, for example "8" - I would like G3 to subtract G24 from it's value (40-8) = 32. If there are no PTO hours entered in G24, I would like for the current 40 hours in G3 to stay the same.

Comment: You can not use formula in same cell you are subtracting. Then you need vba coding. Otherwise you have to display result in another cell like H3.

Comment: See soln below which relies upon VBA (references to how to set this up if you're unfamiliar).

Answer (score 0):

Sheet1 with VB code below does the following:

- Enter value in G3 (sheet1) and it clears G24, and stores this in    hidden sheet (so calc can be repeated for different values of G24 and    same G3)
- Only when G3 selected and changed manually will the hidden sheet be updated to the value you enter
- Enter value in G24 and calc per Question is peformed against original value entered into G3 as described above

Notes: *To insert this macro, make sure workbook is macro-enabled, save as .xlsb or .xlsm), and see [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20220918070130/https://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html) (internet-archived/persistent) link.*

**Macros (Sheet 1 module - comprises 2 subs and 1 function)**

```
Public sheet_name As String


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'https://www.teachexcel.com/excel-tutorial/run-a-macro-when-a-specific-cell-changes-in-excel_1592.html

    sheet_name = "hidden_backup"
    

    If Target.Address = "$G$24" Then
        If ActiveSheet.Range("g24").Value > 0 Then
            If SheetCheck(sheet_name) = True Then
                Range("g3").Value = Sheets(sheet_name).Range("a1").Value - Range("g24").Value
            Else
                MsgBox "populate cell g3 first"
                ActiveSheet.Range("g24").Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    
    End If
    
    
    On Error GoTo err_trap
    If (Target.Address = "$G$3") Then
        'Set cell = ActiveSheet.Selection
        If Not Intersect(Range("g3:g4"), ActiveCell) 
    Then
            Call update_hidden
            Range("g24").Value = ""
        End If
    End If
    
    err_trap: Exit Sub

    
    End Sub
```

---

```
Function SheetCheck(sheet_name) As Boolean
'https://excelchamps.com/vba/add-new-sheet/
'Dim ws As Worksheet

SheetCheck = False
 
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 
    If ws.Name = sheet_name Then
    
        SheetCheck = True
        
    End If
 
Next
 
End Function
```

---

```
Sub update_hidden()
sheet_name = "hidden_backup"
If SheetCheck(sheet_name) = False Then
    
    Worksheets.Add().Name = sheet_name
    
End If

Sheets(sheet_name).Range("a1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Value
Sheets(sheet_name).Visible = False

End Sub
```

---

**Screenshots**

Scenario/illustration:

Step 1: populate g3

[image: Populate G3]

Step 2: populate g24 (calc updates g3)

[image: Populate G24]

Step 3: update/change g24 (calc repeated using original g3 value)

[image: Update G24 and recalc]

Step 4: user updates g3 directly and starts over (1-3)

[image: Update G3 and start over]

---